# Saving product images include previous product's images

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I'm uploading images on this first product and everything seems fine.

However, when I do the same process for the second product, some images from the first product weirdly appears on the second one.

I wonder if this is related to Redis cache, or due to multiple products on Edit Product page on different browser tabs.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's a browser related issue, it could be for Redis Cache.

Comment: @rahul-kumar-das thanks for the answer. I'll give it a try. :)